# PDF Text Extraction: Getting strange Text Elements

Tags: pdf, itext, pdfbox, text-extraction

I tried to get the text from pdfs. Now I encountered a strange issue.

While the pdf looks great in any reader, every `pdf2text` software fails to extract the whole text. I looked at the structure with `iText`, `pdfbox` and the `PDFXplorer`. None of these tools were able to show me all the displayed text of the pdf.

From the appearance of this document I assume that the pdf was generated from a template filled with text. I am able to extracted most of the filled text, but not the text elements of the template.

First I thought it might be a graphical element, but I am able to copy & paste the text form the reader. So there must be a text somewhere in the document.

Here a sample of the strange text elements:

```
BT 65.38 764.23 Td /F0201 7.16 Tf ( !"#$%&'\(#\)*+,+$#-\).#$/#\)012\)34533\)*6-'\(#-7\)8#9,&'\(:!-;) Tj ET
BT 65.38 31.47 Td /F0201 5.37 Tf (<#-,$!:#\)=>?\)3?\)@3AB4) Tj ET
BT 65.38 38.73 Td /F0101 5.37 Tf (&'\('\)*+) Tj ET
BT 65.38 53.24 Td /F0101 5.37 Tf (,-./-+/0123\)4) Tj ET
```

While most of the filled-in text is clear text:

```
BT 163.96 491.22 Td /F0301 12.00 Tf (6030919) Tj ET
BT 70.87 492.07 Td /F0301 12.00 Tf (BESTELLNR.:) Tj ET
BT 235.53 491.22 Td /F0301 12.00 Tf (AEND.-NR.:) Tj ET
BT 342.74 491.22 Td /F0301 12.00 Tf (WAEHRUNG:) Tj ET
```

I read the pdf reference, but I did not find any clue how these *strange* text elements to be interpreted.

Comment: What happens if you copy paste the 'strange' text from Adobe reader to e.g. notepad?

Comment: I am getting the displayed text. Like these "Bezeichnung", "Anforderungsnummer", ... . Directly copied from the PDF.

Comment: This means that the PDF contains sufficient information to extract text. The 'strange' text elements that you see are character codes. They map to Unicode characters using the ToUnicode map, or in the absence of this map, it uses the font encoding. It is not entirely straightforward but PDF libs should do this for you.

Comment: I assume a character encoding here, too. But did not find the right keywords to search for a solution. Do you have an idea where I find such a map in the document or how to decode these "symboles"?

Comment: See the PDF spec. But you would repeat work done in the libs.

Comment: See in particular **5.9 Extraction of Text Content** in PDF-Ref 1.7.

Comment: Thanks I found the position of the relevant information. If I found a solution I will post it here. Thanks for your fast help.

Comment: If the file is not confidential, please file a bug report in PDFBox JIRA or e-mail me the file.

Comment: I find the solution. I used the libs to get the text tokens in a raw version. Leading into tokens encoded as Unicode. Applying the Unicode map reveals the text. Both libs iText and pdfBox providing tools to solve this issue, if you are not need to handle the low level elements has we do (Beside the text we need the position of these too).

Comment: Both iText and PDFBox allow you to use their respective text extraction mechanism with marginal changes to extract text with positions.